# What am I missing that prevents me from making a generic NSStackView-like container with Auto Layout?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, autolayout, nsview

I am trying to implement a container view with Auto Layout **for OS X** that operates similarly to NSStackView, but with a few differences that NSStackView does not handle (and I need 10.7 support anyway). My rules are:

- The subviews are arranged either horizontally or vertically.
- In the primary direction, the subviews by default take their intrinsic size.
- If a subview is marked "stretchy", it will take whatever space remains after laying out all non-stretchy subviews. Multiple stretchy subviews get equal distributions of the remaining space.
- If no subviews are stretchy, the container can grow in the primary direction, showing empty space after the last subview. Nesting two such stacks with the same orientation prefers the outer one.
- Along the secondary direction, subviews clamp to the edges of the container view and grow freely.

I thought this could be done in a simple way, connecting the views in the primary direction one after another and then in the secondary direction using the `|[view]|` visual format. Lack of a stretchy view is handled with a NSView with intrinsic content size 0x0 as the last view.

This mostly worked. Unfortunately, ambiguity arose with a nested tree of horizontally oriented stacks of the form (represented using HTML for expository purposes)

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
}

.outermost-box {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outermost-box">
  <div class="box">
    <input type="button" value="These">
    <input type="button" value="Buttons" disabled>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="button" value="are">
    <div class="box">
      <input type="button" value="in" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box">
      <input type="button" value="nested">
      <div class="box">
        <input type="button" value="boxes" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

where all the stacks have no stretchy subviews. Under my definition, the outermost box stretches, and only that one stretches. However, Auto Layout will randomly assign the extra space to one of the inner boxes:

[image: Auto Layout misbehaving part 1; notice how "nested boxes" is flush right with the edge of the window when it's supposed to be flush left next to "These buttons are in"]

Changing the extra view to a `NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual` relation (`last view.trailing <= superview.trailing`) also did not help. I'm going to keep this model for the rest of this post, though, as my next attempts are based on it.

Then I decided to try having the container ask its superview if it should expand. This fixed the above problem, but introduced another problem with deep chains of containers that alternate between horizontal and vertical:

[image: Auto Layout misbehaving part 2]

The buttons labelled "Right Margin Test" *should* stretch, but they either aren't stretching or are stretching but also clipping the views on the sides (I don't have a screenshot of this right now; sorry).

Then I decided to have both the `<=` and alternate `==` constraints on the right edge on at the same time, setting `==` to a low priority if there should be extra space. This new one mostly works, but now has a weird problem. If I resize the window large enough on the Page 3 shown above, then switch to Page 4, I get

[image: Auto Layout misbehaving part 4]

and then if I resize I get

[image: Auto Layout misbehaving part 5]

even though Page 4 should have space at the bottom under all conditions. Sometimes the bottom of the button can be seen, and visualizing its vertical constraints show it thinks it wants to be as tall as the matrix of radio buttons (right now a NSMatrix; changing it to a bunch of NSButtons will wait until after I fix all these Auto Layout issues).

I'm really not sure what's going on or how to fix any of this. I tried making the `==` constraint I mentioned have a settable "real hugging priority" of its own, but that just made things break in more spectacular ways.'

There's also problems with positions of tab views being too low initially and taking a few layout cycles to set properly...

Everything shown is done with these containers, NSBoxes with one subview, and NSTabs with one subview. I'll paste the code for my container as it stands now below.

So what about Auto Layout do I not understand that I can't just make it work right with the obvious code? Or can NSStackView do all of what I want and I should just use it instead? (That assumes `alignment` takes `Width` and `Height` as valid, which Interface Builder does not seem to say it does).

Thanks!

```
// 15 august 2015
#import "uipriv_darwin.h"

// TODOs:
// - tab on page 2 is glitched initially and doesn't grow
// - page 3 doesn't work right; probably due to our shouldExpand logic being applied incorrectly

// TODOs to confirm
// - 10.8: if we switch to page 4, then switch back to page 1, check Spaced, and go back to page 4, some controls (progress bar, popup button) are clipped on the sides

@interface boxChild : NSObject
@property uiControl *c;
@property BOOL stretchy;
@property NSLayoutPriority oldHorzHuggingPri;
@property NSLayoutPriority oldVertHuggingPri;
- (NSView *)view;
@end

@interface boxView : NSView {
    uiBox *b;
    NSMutableArray *children;
    BOOL vertical;
    int padded;

    NSLayoutConstraint *first;
    NSMutableArray *inBetweens;
    NSLayoutConstraint *last, *last2;
    NSMutableArray *otherConstraints;

    NSLayoutAttribute primaryStart;
    NSLayoutAttribute primaryEnd;
    NSLayoutAttribute secondaryStart;
    NSLayoutAttribute secondaryEnd;
    NSLayoutAttribute primarySize;
    NSLayoutConstraintOrientation primaryOrientation;
    NSLayoutConstraintOrientation secondaryOrientation;
}
- (id)initWithVertical:(BOOL)vert b:(uiBox *)bb;
- (void)onDestroy;
- (void)removeOurConstraints;
- (void)forAll:(void (^)(uintmax_t i, boxChild *b))closure;
- (boxChild *)child:(uintmax_t)i;
- (BOOL)isVertical;
- (void)append:(uiControl *)c stretchy:(int)stretchy;
- (void)delete:(uintmax_t)n;
- (int)isPadded;
- (void)setPadded:(int)p;
@end

struct uiBox {
    uiDarwinControl c;
    boxView *view;
};

@implementation boxChild

- (NSView *)view
{
    return (NSView *) uiControlHandle(self.c);
}

@end

@implementation boxView

- (id)initWithVertical:(BOOL)vert b:(uiBox *)bb
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    if (self != nil) {
        // the weird names vert and bb are to shut the compiler up about shadowing because implicit this/self is stupid
        self->b = bb;
        self->vertical = vert;
        self->children = [NSMutableArray new];
        self->inBetweens = [NSMutableArray new];
        self->otherConstraints = [NSMutableArray new];

        if (self->vertical) {
            self->primaryStart = NSLayoutAttributeTop;
            self->primaryEnd = NSLayoutAttributeBottom;
            self->secondaryStart = NSLayoutAttributeLeading;
            self->secondaryEnd = NSLayoutAttributeTrailing;
            self->primarySize = NSLayoutAttributeHeight;
            self->primaryOrientation = NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical;
            self->secondaryOrientation = NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal;
        } else {
            self->primaryStart = NSLayoutAttributeLeading;
            self->primaryEnd = NSLayoutAttributeTrailing;
            self->secondaryStart = NSLayoutAttributeTop;
            self->secondaryEnd = NSLayoutAttributeBottom;
            self->primarySize = NSLayoutAttributeWidth;
            self->primaryOrientation = NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal;
            self->secondaryOrientation = NSLayoutConstraintOrientationVertical;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)onDestroy
{
    boxChild *bc;
    uintmax_t i, n;

    [self removeOurConstraints];
    [self->first release];
    [self->inBetweens release];
    [self->last release];
    [self->last2 release];
    [self->otherConstraints release];

    n = [self->children count];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        bc = [self child:i];
        uiControlSetParent(bc.c, NULL);
        uiDarwinControlSetSuperview(uiDarwinControl(bc.c), nil);
        uiControlDestroy(bc.c);
    }
    [self->children release];
}

- (void)removeOurConstraints
{
    [self removeConstraint:self->first];
    [self removeConstraints:self->inBetweens];
    [self removeConstraint:self->last];
    [self removeConstraint:self->last2];
    [self removeConstraints:self->otherConstraints];
}

- (void)forAll:(void (^)(uintmax_t i, boxChild *b))closure
{
    uintmax_t i, n;

    n = [self->children count];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        closure(i, [self child:i]);
}

- (boxChild *)child:(uintmax_t)i
{
    return (boxChild *) [self->children objectAtIndex:i];
}

- (BOOL)isVertical
{
    return self->vertical;
}

// TODO something about spinbox hugging
- (void)updateConstraints
{
    uintmax_t i, n;
    BOOL hasStretchy;
    NSView *firstStretchy = nil;
    CGFloat padding;
    NSView *prev, *next;
    NSLayoutConstraint *c;
    NSLayoutPriority priority;

    [super updateConstraints];
    [self removeOurConstraints];

    n = [self->children count];
    if (n == 0)
        return;
    padding = 0;
    if (self->padded)
        padding = 8.0;      // TODO named constant

    // first, attach the first view to the leading
    prev = [[self child:0] view];
    self->first = mkConstraint(prev, self->primaryStart,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        self, self->primaryStart,
        1, 0,
        @"uiBox first primary constraint");
    [self addConstraint:self->first];
    [self->first retain];

    // next, assemble the views in the primary direction
    // they all go in a straight line
    // also figure out whether we have stretchy controls, and which is the first
    if ([self child:0].stretchy) {
        hasStretchy = YES;
        firstStretchy = prev;
    } else
        hasStretchy = NO;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        next = [[self child:i] view];
        if (!hasStretchy && [self child:i].stretchy) {
            hasStretchy = YES;
            firstStretchy = next;
        }
        c = mkConstraint(next, self->primaryStart,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            prev, self->primaryEnd,
            1, padding,
            @"uiBox later primary constraint");
        [self addConstraint:c];
        [self->inBetweens addObject:c];
        prev = next;
    }

    // and finally end the primary direction
    self->last = mkConstraint(prev, self->primaryEnd,
        NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual,
        self, self->primaryEnd,
        1, 0,
        @"uiBox last primary constraint");
    [self addConstraint:self->last];
    [self->last retain];

    // if there is a stretchy control, add the no-stretchy view
    self->last2 = mkConstraint(prev, self->primaryEnd,
        NSLayoutRelationEqual,
        self, self->primaryEnd,
        1, 0,
        @"uiBox last2 primary constraint");
    priority = NSLayoutPriorityRequired;
    if (!hasStretchy) {
        BOOL shouldExpand = NO;
        uiControl *parent;

        parent = uiControlParent(uiControl(self->b));
        if (parent != nil)
            if (self->vertical)
                shouldExpand = uiDarwinControlChildrenShouldAllowSpaceAtBottom(uiDarwinControl(parent));
            else
                shouldExpand = uiDarwinControlChildrenShouldAllowSpaceAtTrailingEdge(uiDarwinControl(parent));
        if (shouldExpand)
            priority = NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow;
    }
    [self->last2 setPriority:priority];
    [self addConstraint:self->last2];
    [self->last2 retain];

    // next: assemble the views in the secondary direction
    // each of them will span the secondary direction
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        prev = [[self child:i] view];
        c = mkConstraint(prev, self->secondaryStart,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            self, self->secondaryStart,
            1, 0,
            @"uiBox start secondary constraint");
        [self addConstraint:c];
        [self->otherConstraints addObject:c];
        c = mkConstraint(prev, self->secondaryEnd,
            NSLayoutRelationEqual,
            self, self->secondaryEnd,
            1, 0,
            @"uiBox end secondary constraint");
        [self addConstraint:c];
        [self->otherConstraints addObject:c];
    }

    // finally, set sizes for stretchy controls
    if (hasStretchy)
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (![self child:i].stretchy)
                continue;
            prev = [[self child:i] view];
            if (prev == firstStretchy)
                continue;
            c = mkConstraint(prev, self->primarySize,
                NSLayoutRelationEqual,
                firstStretchy, self->primarySize,
                1, 0,
                @"uiBox stretchy sizing");
            [self addConstraint:c];
            [self->otherConstraints addObject:c];
        }
}

- (void)append:(uiControl *)c stretchy:(int)stretchy
{
    boxChild *bc;
    NSView *childView;

    bc = [boxChild new];
    bc.c = c;
    bc.stretchy = stretchy;
    childView = [bc view];
    bc.oldHorzHuggingPri = horzHuggingPri(childView);
    bc.oldVertHuggingPri = vertHuggingPri(childView);

    uiControlSetParent(bc.c, uiControl(self->b));
    uiDarwinControlSetSuperview(uiDarwinControl(bc.c), self);
    uiDarwinControlSyncEnableState(uiDarwinControl(bc.c), uiControlEnabledToUser(uiControl(self->b)));

    // if a control is stretchy, it should not hug in the primary direction
    // otherwise, it should *forcibly* hug
    if (stretchy)
        setHuggingPri(childView, NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow, self->primaryOrientation);
    else
        // TODO will default high work?
        setHuggingPri(childView, NSLayoutPriorityRequired, self->primaryOrientation);
    // make sure controls don't hug their secondary direction so they fill the width of the view
    setHuggingPri(childView, NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow, self->secondaryOrientation);

    [self->children addObject:bc];
    [bc release];       // we don't need the initial reference now

    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints:YES];
}

- (void)delete:(uintmax_t)n
{
    boxChild *bc;
    NSView *removedView;

    bc = [self child:n];
    removedView = [bc view];

    uiControlSetParent(bc.c, NULL);
    uiDarwinControlSetSuperview(uiDarwinControl(bc.c), nil);

    setHorzHuggingPri(removedView, bc.oldHorzHuggingPri);
    setVertHuggingPri(removedView, bc.oldVertHuggingPri);

    [self->children removeObjectAtIndex:n];

    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints:YES];
}

- (int)isPadded
{
    return self->padded;
}

- (void)setPadded:(int)p
{
    CGFloat padding;
    uintmax_t i, n;
    NSLayoutConstraint *c;

    self->padded = p;

    // TODO split into method (using above code)
    padding = 0;
    if (self->padded)
        padding = 8.0;
    n = [self->inBetweens count];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c = (NSLayoutConstraint *) [self->inBetweens objectAtIndex:i];
        [c setConstant:padding];
    }
    // TODO call anything?
}

@end

static void uiBoxDestroy(uiControl *c)
{
    uiBox *b = uiBox(c);

    [b->view onDestroy];
    [b->view release];
    uiFreeControl(uiControl(b));
}

uiDarwinControlDefaultHandle(uiBox, view)
uiDarwinControlDefaultParent(uiBox, view)
uiDarwinControlDefaultSetParent(uiBox, view)
uiDarwinControlDefaultToplevel(uiBox, view)
uiDarwinControlDefaultVisible(uiBox, view)
uiDarwinControlDefaultShow(uiBox, view)
uiDarwinControlDefaultHide(uiBox, view)
uiDarwinControlDefaultEnabled(uiBox, view)
uiDarwinControlDefaultEnable(uiBox, view)
uiDarwinControlDefaultDisable(uiBox, view)

static void uiBoxSyncEnableState(uiDarwinControl *c, int enabled)
{
    uiBox *b = uiBox(c);

    if (uiDarwinShouldStopSyncEnableState(uiDarwinControl(b), enabled))
        return;
    [b->view forAll:^(uintmax_t i, boxChild *bc) {
        uiDarwinControlSyncEnableState(uiDarwinControl(bc.c), enabled);
    }];
}

uiDarwinControlDefaultSetSuperview(uiBox, view)

static BOOL uiBoxChildrenShouldAllowSpaceAtTrailingEdge(uiDarwinControl *c)
{
    uiBox *b = uiBox(c);

    // return NO if this box is horizontal so nested horizontal boxes don't lead to ambiguity
    return [b->view isVertical];
}

static BOOL uiBoxChildrenShouldAllowSpaceAtBottom(uiDarwinControl *c)
{
    uiBox *b = uiBox(c);

    // return NO if this box is vertical so nested vertical boxes don't lead to ambiguity
    return ![b->view isVertical];
}

void uiBoxAppend(uiBox *b, uiControl *c, int stretchy)
{
    [b->view append:c stretchy:stretchy];
}

void uiBoxDelete(uiBox *b, uintmax_t n)
{
    [b->view delete:n];
}

int uiBoxPadded(uiBox *b)
{
    return [b->view isPadded];
}

void uiBoxSetPadded(uiBox *b, int padded)
{
    [b->view setPadded:padded];
}

static uiBox *finishNewBox(BOOL vertical)
{
    uiBox *b;

    uiDarwinNewControl(uiBox, b);

    b->view = [[boxView alloc] initWithVertical:vertical b:b];

    return b;
}

uiBox *uiNewHorizontalBox(void)
{
    return finishNewBox(NO);
}

uiBox *uiNewVerticalBox(void)
{
    return finishNewBox(YES);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this myself.

The primary change is that instead of having the has-extra-space-after-it is not done by the constraints on self, but on its superview. The superview asks self if it should take the extra space, and if so, it allocates the extra space (using a >= constraint to the superview edge instead of a == constraint).

A variety of other minor fixes fixes the edge case. In particular, everywhere where I do

```
relation = NSLayoutRelationSomething;
if (condition)
    relation = NSLayoutRelationSomethingElse;
constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithArg:arg arg:arg
    relation:relation
    ...]
```

I change to using two constraints, setting the priority of them both based on the condition. **This should probably be an Auto Layout best practice, since it works so well...**

Thanks anyway!